# Installer is stuck when installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I started installing Ubuntu this afternoon at 17:00. It is now 00:21 and it still hasn't finished. Is this normal? If I turn the machine off before it is finished, given that I've already formatted everything, will I be unable to turn it on again?

Comment: Hi Eleazar, the site language is English, could you please translate from Spain and elaborate a bit?

Comment: Lo siento pero aquí solo hablemos ingles. Puedes utilizar algo como el [google translate](http://translate.google.com) y traducir tu pregunta (y las posibles respuestas). Este vez, te lo hice yo pero en el futuro tendras que escribirlo en Ingles.

Comment: At what point of the installation process is it stuck? What does the screen show?

Comment: Usually the worst thing that can happen is that your installation does not work. If the disk is already formatted, the previous system is gone, of course. But you can boot live systems from a CD/DVD/USB and of course restart the installation. Sometimes it fails first and works on the second attempt... (Nobody knows why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: No, you will not be able to turn it back on without restarting everything from the start.  The cause of this could be a number of things, including a bad CD/DVD, dirty DVD/CD lens, ...